# About the order of a group element

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I'm studying Cauchy theorem in Group Theory and I found an interesting proof in the book Visual Group Theory.
At the beginning of this proof, there's a claim which puzzles me a bit (here G is a finite group, $g\in G$ and p is a prime):

"Because p is prime, if I find some $g\ne e$ satisfying $g^p=e$, then $g$ must have order p."

Actually what make me think is the definition of the order of an element is precisely "a number n which makes $g^n=e$, and this no matter if n is prime or not. So that sentence it seems to me a bit over-constrained, since it would be true no matter if p is prime or not.

Where am I wrong in my reasoning, please?

Thank as always for your support.

Comment: The order is the SMALLEST positive power making that happen.  If $n>0$ and you know that $g^n=e$, the order must divide $n$:  it need not *be* $n$.

Comment: Ah OK, so in this case having p prime guarantees this is also the minimum exponent satisfying that equality, since as prime can be divided only by 1 or by p, and so p is the order in that case. I really think it could worth raising your comment as an answer, possibly. Thank @Randall.

Comment: @riccardoventrella Already done so....with an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, in general it does *not* follow from $g^n=e$ that $g$ has order $n$, because already $g^{n/d}=e$ could hold for a divisor of $n$. However, if $n=p$ is prime, then of course it *does* follow. As an example, take
$G=GL_2(\Bbb Z)$ and
$$
g=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \cr 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Of course, $g^4=e$, but the order of $g$ is $2$.

Comment: An easier example is just to notice that $4 \cdot 2=0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_4$, yet the order of $2$ is actually just $2$.

Comment: Thank @Dietrich, this answer definitely makes me happy.

Comment: @Randall Yes, I know that this is easier, but I had the experience that for many people group theory becomes less abstract when you consider matrices, whereas quotients $R/I$, well, ...

Comment: Fair. My experience has been the opposite.  (They tend to trust more the finite and abelian examples.)

Comment: Actually, being devoted to abstract Math, I'm more on @Randall page. For example, if I have an abstract group, I usually try to find a permutation representation of it, instead of a matrix one. This is more natural to me, but of course it's according to taste. Both your examples are meaningful to me guys. Thanks for that.

Comment: I understand. I just like $GL_2(\Bbb Z)$  very much, e.g., because of the $17$ wallpaper groups...

Comment: To be clear, I wasn't criticizing the original answer at all, just adding to.  Matrices are great.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, I'm not an expert on wallpaper groups, even if I studied them a bit with Conways' "Symmetry of things". May you explain briefly how they actually relate to $GL_2(\Bbb{Z})$? Thanks for that

Comment: @riccardoventrella The algebraic classification of the $17$ wallpaper groups directly comes from the classification of the arithmetic ornament classes, i.e., the conjugacy classes of finite subgroups of $GL_2(\Bbb Z)$. There are $13$ such classes, giving $17$ wallpaper groups. The reason is that the translations in a wallpaper group form a lattice $\Bbb Z^2$ and ${\rm Aut}(\Bbb Z^2)$ is just $GL_2(\Bbb Z)$.

Comment: Cool, you explained it very effectively. Thanks for that, I will dwelve in it further, since interesting. Actually, I don't know if this could be strictly related, but I'm studying yet another $Aut(\Bbb{Z}/n)$ related to Fermat Little Theorem. A good tutorial on that is this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4psS2Gys_SU&list=PLF379B0552AD17780&index=21